# How do I use androids LayoutInflater.Factory to create a custom view class instead of a built in class?

Tags: android, view, factory

I am using a custom class based off RelativeLayout but it obviously doesn't render in the Eclipse layout editor.

I have found this article regarding LayoutInflater.Factory and it sounds like what I need to be doing but I can find no guides to using LayoutInflater.Factory.

http://www.macadamian.com/blog/post/android_-_custom_classes_from_xml_layout/

Could anyone help with exactly what and where I do this? I understand what is said in the article, but need specifics on where to declare, hook, whatever the Factory.

In case it is helpful, here is the complete console output from when I try to view main.xml in Layout view..

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:396)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle1.GraphicalLayoutEditor.computeLayout(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle1.GraphicalLayoutEditor.recomputeLayout(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle1.GraphicalLayoutEditor.activated(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1076)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:601)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.selectDefaultPage(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:357)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:662)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:462)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1256)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.presentationSelectionChanged(PartStack.java:843)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.access$1(PartStack.java:829)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack$1.selectPart(PartStack.java:139)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation$1.handleEvent(TabbedStackPresentation.java:133)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.AbstractTabFolder.fireEvent(AbstractTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder.access$1(DefaultTabFolder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.defaultpresentation.DefaultTabFolder$2.handleEvent(DefaultTabFolder.java:87)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1185)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1025)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3256)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:2045)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:323)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LayoutInflater.Factory is not what you want. The Eclipse editor is perfectly capable to showing custom views, you should check the error logs in case there's something wrong going on.

Comment: Yet the article mentions exactly my problem, that it fails to draw the object due to a cast error between View and ViewGroup. Since my custom RelativeLayout simply has some extra onClick event handling, I am at a loss as to how that can be fixed if at all.

Comment: Ah. Is this because I am asking a ViewGroup to implement onClickListener which is from View and not ViewGroup?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It wasn't a problem casting this object, but rather another ViewGroup inside it which was being treated as a View in the code.